# copy one bson mongo collection data in other server

Tags: mongodb

I have a **mongo** database say `xyz` in my localhost server and `xyz` in UAT server (ip server).

Now i have a huge one collection in localhost (cities name). what i did - taken a dump of it and i got `cities.bson` file in my c:/ drive, now i want to put only `cities.bson` data in UAT mongo server.

Any clue how it can be achieved?

Comment: I have a feeling that you could add some more information. Try to elaborate the question.

Comment: @xenteros updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongorestore to restore individual collections from bson documents.

You're looking for something along the lines of:

```
> mongorestore --host <new_host_name> --port <new_port_name> --db <db_name> --collection <collection_name> /path/to/your/bson/file
```